# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str: What does it mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, random

```
from tkinter import*
import random
from tkinter import messagebox
window=Tk()
window.title("Random Tools")
window.configure(background="light green")
textvaria = IntVar()
textvaria2 = IntVar()

label0 = Label(window, text = "Min", bg ="light green")
label0.grid(row=1, column=0)

spinboxmin = Spinbox(window, from_=1, to=9999, increment=1, textvariable=textvaria)
spinboxmin.grid(row=2, column=0)
a = spinboxmin.get()

label1 = Label(window, text="Max", bg="light green")
label1.grid(row=3, column=0)

spinboxmax = Spinbox(window, from_=1, to=9999, increment=1, textvariable=textvaria2)
spinboxmax.grid(row = 4, column =0)
b = spinboxmax.get()

def submit2():
    if a <= b:
        answertext.delete('1.0', END)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Max must be greater than min!")

submit = Button(text="Submit", command=submit2)
submit.grid(row=4, column=2)

n = random.randint(a, b+1)

answertext = Text(text=n)
answertext.grid(row=5, column=0)


window.mainloop()
```

I'm doing a GUI for randoming numbers. But when I run this in Python Module, it said: 
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"
Can someone help me with this?
Thank a lot.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on [spinbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm) states that get() method returns the current contents of the spinbox as a string. You can't add a number to a string like you are trying to do on here

```
n = random.randint(a, b+1)
```

So you must convert b to int then add to it.

```
n = random.randint(a, int(b)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace :

```
a  = spinboxmin.get()
b = spinboxmax.get()
```

With:

```
a = textvaria.get()
b = textvaria2.get()
```